# add custom elements based on css styles not images to chart D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new in D3.js.
I have created chart, example is here http://ifeel.inmanage.com/_modules/charts.html

As you can see there is a flag icons, that is images, and what i am trying to do, that draw a horizontal lines from flag to bottom line  like here [image]

I already try to do it with lot of ways and can't get the right result.
Thank's for any advice
You can see my code in playground here:

```js
;
var ifeel_graph = function(d3_obj) {

  var self = this,
    _d3 = d3_obj || d3;

  self.opt = {
    chart: '',
    xScale: 0,
    yScale: 0,
    xAxis: 0,
    yAxis: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    margins: 0,
    paddings: 0,
    xStartPoint: 0,
    xEndPoint: 0,
    yStartPoint: 0,
    yEndPoint: 0
  };

  self.charGroup = {
    patient: {
      styles: {},
      attr: {}
    },
    caregiver: {
      styles: {},
      attr: {}
    },
    trustbuddy: {
      styles: {},
      attr: {}
    }
  }

  self.dateFormat = {
    byMonthName: _d3.time.format("%B"),
    byDayName: _d3.time.format("%A"),
    byDefault: _d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"),
    byMultyFormat: _d3.time.format.multi([
      [".%L",
        function(d) {
          return d.getMilliseconds();
        }
      ],
      [":%S",
        function(d) {
          return d.getSeconds();
        }
      ],
      ["%I:%M",
        function(d) {
          return d.getMinutes();
        }
      ],
      ["%I %p",
        function(d) {
          return d.getHours();
        }
      ],
      ["%a %d",
        function(d) {
          return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1;
        }
      ],
      ["%b %d",
        function(d) {
          return d.getDate() != 1;
        }
      ],
      ["%B",
        function(d) {
          return d.getMonth();
        }
      ],
      ["%Y",
        function() {
          return true;
        }
      ]
    ])

  };

  self.init = function(data) {

  };

  self.addOptions = function(key, value) {

    self.opt[key] = data;
    return self;
  };

}


var xScale, yScale, xAxis, yAxis, lineGen;
var monthNameFormat = d3.time.format("%B");
var dayNameFormat = d3.time.format("%A");
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
var chart = d3.select('#visualisation');
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "graph-tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);
var width = 550,
  height = 350,
  padding = 100;

var margings = {
    top: 15,
    right: 45,
    bottom: 15,
    left: 50
  },
  paddings = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50,
    all: 100
  };

var mindate = new Date(2016, 00, 01),
  maxdate = new Date(2016, 00, 07);

var lineData = {
  patient: [{
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 01),
    'value': '0'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 02),
    'value': '0'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 03),
    'value': '0'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 04),
    'value': '0'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 05),
    'value': '8'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 06),
    'value': '1'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 07),
    'value': '9.5'
  }],
  trustbuddy: [{
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 01),
    'value': '8'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 02),
    'value': '5'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 03),
    'value': '3.6'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 04),
    'value': '9'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 05),
    'value': '1'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 06),
    'value': '4.5'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 07),
    'value': '1'
  }],
  caregiver: [{
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 01),
    'value': '1'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 02),
    'value': '6'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 03),
    'value': '2'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 04),
    'value': '9'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 05),
    'value': '5.5'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 06),
    'value': '8.3'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 07),
    'value': '2.3'
  }],
  flags: [{
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 07),
    'value': '5'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 03),
    'value': '8'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 05),
    'value': '2'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 02),
    'value': '10'
  }, {
    'date': new Date(2016, 00, 01),
    'value': '4'
  }]
};

// xScale = d3.time.scale()
xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([mindate, maxdate])
  .range([margings.left, width - margings.right]); //x scale

yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 10.5])
  .range([height - margings.top, margings.bottom]); //y scale


xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(7)
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m-%d")); //creating x Axis*/


yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient("left")
  .scale(yScale); //creating y Axis and moving it left


chart.append("svg:g")
  .attr("stroke", "#BFC1C1")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margings.left) + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis); //appending with transform Yaxis

chart.append("svg:g")
  .attr("stroke", "#BFC1C1")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("class", "xaxis")
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margings.bottom) + ")")
  .call(xAxis); //appending with transform x Axis

chart.append("text")
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("x", 30)
  .attr("class", "graph-title")
  .style("text-anchor", "right")
  // .style("fill", "red")
  .style("font-size", 20)
  .text("VAS");


chart.selectAll(".xaxis text") // select all the text elements for the xaxis
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + this.getBBox().height * -1 + "," + this.getBBox().height + ")rotate(-35)";
  })
  .attr('fill', '#003C4C')
  .attr('stroke', 'none');


lineGen = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.date);
  }).y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value);
  });

var img_icon_flag = {
  src: 'http://ifeel.inmanage.com/_media/images/icons/flag.png',
  width: 41,
  height: 30,
  x: (width / 2),
  y: height - 319 - 15
};


chart.append('svg:path')
  .attr('d', lineGen(lineData.patient))
  .attr('stroke', '#FB741A')
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'none');


chart.append('svg:path')
  .attr('d', lineGen(lineData.caregiver))
  .attr('stroke', '#003C4C')
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'none');


chart.append('svg:path')
  .attr('d', lineGen(lineData.trustbuddy))
  .attr('stroke', '#5DDDFD')
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'none');


//events-flag

chart.selectAll("dot")
  .data(lineData.patient)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr('stroke', 'none')
  .attr('fill', '#FB741A')
  .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.date);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value);
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9)
      .style('background-color', '#FB741A');
    //.style('border-style', 'solid')
    //.style('border-width', '1px');
    div.html(d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });

chart.selectAll("dot")
  .data(lineData.caregiver)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr('stroke', 'none')
  .attr('fill', '#003C4C')
  .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.date);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value);
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9)
      .style('background-color', '#003C4C');
    // .style('border-style', 'solid')
    //.style('border-width', '1px');
    div.html(d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });


chart.selectAll("dot")
  .data(lineData.trustbuddy)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr('stroke', 'none')
  .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
  .attr('fill', '#5DDDFD')
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.date);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value);
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9)
      .style('background-color', '#5DDDFD')
      //.style('border-style', 'solid')
      //.style('border-width', '1px');
    div.html(d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });

for (var flag in lineData.flags) {
  console.log(lineData.flags[flag])
  chart.append("svg:image")
    .data([lineData.flags[flag]])
    .attr({
      "xlink:href": img_icon_flag.src,
      "width": img_icon_flag.width,
      "height": img_icon_flag.height,
      "x": function(d) {
        return xScale(d.date);
      },
      "y": function(d) {
        return yScale(d.value);
      }
    })
}

//appendImageToGraph(chart,img_icon_flag.src, img_icon_flag.width, img_icon_flag.height);
//appendImageToGraph(chart,img_short_flag.src, img_short_flag.width, img_short_flag.height, img_short_flag.x, img_short_flag.y);


function parseDateForViewing(d) {
  return d3.time.format('%b %Y')(d3.time.format('%m/%d/%Y').parse(d));
}

function parseDate2(d) {
  return d3.time.format('%c')(d3.time.format('%m/%d/%Y').parse(d));
}


function appendImageToGraph(elem, img, width, height) {

  return (function() {


    for (var flag in lineData.flags) {

      elem.append("svg:image")
        .data(lineData.flags[flag])
        .attr({
          "xlink:href": img,
          "width": width,
          "height": height,
          "x": function(d) {
            return xScale(d.date);
          },
          "y": function(d) {
            return yScale(d.value);
          }
        })
    }


    //            elem.append("svg:image")
    //                .data(lineData.flags)
    //                .attr({"xlink:href": img,
    //                    "width": width,
    //                    "height": height,
    //                    "x": function(d) { return xScale(d.date); },
    //                    "y": function(d) { return yScale(d.value); }
    //                })
    //                .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
    //                .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.value); });

  })();
};

var formatM = d3.time.format.multi([
  [".%L",
    function(d) {
      return d.getMilliseconds();
    }
  ],
  [":%S",
    function(d) {
      return d.getSeconds();
    }
  ],
  ["%I:%M",
    function(d) {
      return d.getMinutes();
    }
  ],
  ["%I %p",
    function(d) {
      return d.getHours();
    }
  ],
  ["%a %d",
    function(d) {
      return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1;
    }
  ],
  ["%b %d",
    function(d) {
      return d.getDate() != 1;
    }
  ],
  ["%B",
    function(d) {
      return d.getMonth();
    }
  ],
  ["%Y",
    function() {
      return true;
    }
  ]
]);
```

```css
.axis text {
  display: none;
}
.special {} .graph-title {
  fill: rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.8);
}
.graph-statistic-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*margin-left: -2.5%;*/
}
.graph-statistic-list > li {
  margin: 2% 0 0 0;
}
.graph-container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
div.graph-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 26px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #232323;
  text-align: center;
  /*background: #BFC1C1;*/
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="graph-container">
    <svg id="visualisation" width="550" height="400"></svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should draw lines with the data like so:

```
chart.append('svg:g')
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(lineData.flags)
        .enter()
        .append('line')
            .attr('x1', function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
            .attr('y1', function(d) { return yScale(d.value); })
            .attr('x2', function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
            .attr('y2', height - 20)

chart.append('svg:g')
    .selectAll('image')
        .data(lineData.flags)
        .enter()
        .append('image')
            .attr("xlink:href", img_icon_flag.src)
            .attr("width", img_icon_flag.width)
            .attr("height", img_icon_flag.height)
            .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.date); } )
            .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.value); } )
```

To see the lines you should put in your css

```
line {
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #BFC1C1;
}
```